# Увеличение высоты div в вверх

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Здравствуйте, вопрос будет туповат, но не знаю как реализовать это.
Есть див, к которому применена css-анимация увеличения его ширины и высоты. 
Проблема в том, что при увеличении высоты, нижняя граница дива сползает вниз, как сделать так, чтобы она оставалась на прежнем месте и высота дива расширялась вверх. 
Думаю, посмотрев пример станет понятно чего я хочу добиться. Заранее спасибо

```css
body{
  margin:50px;
}
div{
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  border-right:2px solid black;
  animation: width-up 3s;
 animation-duration:5s;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes width-up {
   from { width: 0px;height:0px }
   50%{ width: 200px;height:0px }
     to { width: 200px;height:30px }
}

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А вы хотите чтобы он рос вверх или стоял на середине?

Comment: нижняя граница должна оставаться на месте и не двигаться, а боковая правая должна расти вверх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо задать абсолютную позицию зафиксировать bottom и все

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  animation: width-up 3s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes width-up {
  from {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px
  }
  50% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```